# Why my docker container with SSL does not work?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, ssl, dockerfile

My startup.cs has suitable to https. I used it into Windows Server. But i want to implement docker technology. I have achieved it without https. After im passing https it did not work anymore. Here is my docker run command =>

```
docker run --name containername -p 8081:80 -p 8082:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8082 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="mypass" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/myssl.pfx -v rbpc\.dotnet\https -e DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false -d username/repositoryname:versionname
```

This is my errors on docker cli =>

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]

      Unable to start Kestrel.

      Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file

         at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)

         at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)

         at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)

         at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Certificates.CertificateConfigLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert()

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Unhandled exception. Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file

   at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)

   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)

   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)

   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Certificates.CertificateConfigLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadDefaultCert()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)

   at MyWebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/MyWebApi/Program.cs:line 16
```

Comment: In my docker-compose I have `__` between the parts after `ASPNETCORE_` (i.e. `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password`). Does that make a difference?

Comment: I have added your advice and error changed to x509 @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: Your volume mount appears to be invalid: `-v rbpc\.dotnet\https`. I expect you want `-v rbpc\.dotnetnet\https://https`

Comment: your solution gives me an error which is "docker: Error response from daemon: create rbpc\.dotnet\https: "rbpc\\.dotnet\\https" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

Comment: Ah, you'll need the full path for `rbpc\.dotnet\https` then (I also seemed to typo it). That is a folder on the host machine, right?

Comment: I have added c:\users\rbpc\.dotnet\https but the error does not change. It is the same error. Yes, the folder is on the host machine. @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: I'm not 100% sure then. I've just tried this: `docker run --rm -it -v c:\users\john:/john ubuntu:16.04` and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--user ContainerAdministrator` should fix the issue.